# React-router having trouble display each of the components on its own

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm migrating to ReactRouter v4 and it's just been proving a hassle to me. I have a file in app.js in which i'm trying to setup a simple routing system.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, Redirect } from 'react-router';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route exact path='/' component={NavigationBar}></Route>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The code compiles perfectly well, but for some reason on the browser, the navigation bar is shown instead of the login page when the url is localhost:3000/login

[The image of the nagivation bar showing instead of the login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFPdf.png)

I intended the login to be shown at /login and the navigation bar to be shown at /, but instead the navigation bar is shown at both /login and /. 
I've been following the examples on the react-router training guide here, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's just a typo in your post here, but you're extending `Compoent` instead of `Component`. I would guess you'd see worse issues than getting the wrong component if that was happening in your code.

I prefer BrowserRouter (I don't have to support legacy browsers), but I got your code working like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path='/' component={NavigationBar}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage}></Route>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

You'll have to install `react-router-dom` for this code to run.

Visiting http://localhost:3000/#/login, I get the Login component. If you change `HashRouter` to `BrowserRouter`, you can see your component render at http://localhost:3000/login.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. It's kind of weird that changing the router can't make it act really weird. Do you always use BrowserRouter for you react projects? Are other routers suited only for certain scenarios?